Can a fridge and a countertop 900W microwave use the same outlet (but different receptacle)?
The flat plugs prevent the use of the other receptacle on both the countertop microwave and the fridge. I am wondering if this is by design or if I should replace the box with a 2 gang and put one one-receptacle gfci outlet in each gang.

You're almost guaranteed to blow the breaker that way unless you have a split receptacle on two circuits. Which is it? If you have two circuits, look for a rotating outlet which solves the plug problem.

The design is not to block your outlets, it is to allow these appliances to be installed in a dedicated cubby with an outlet on the rear wall, and to be pushed close to the wall without damaging the cord.

What's the nameplate power of your fridge?   With any luck it's on the inside door frame, you don't have to move it.   What is the Amp rating of the circuit breaker for this outlet?

@isherwood No. It is exceedingly unlikely to trip even a 15A breaker (and kitchen circuits should be 20A). A 900W microwave draws maybe 9A. A refrigerator takes 1A or 2A continuous. Startup might take 10A for a second or two, but a 33% overload will not trip a breaker in a second or two.

Fair enough. Those numbers seem a bit low, and bring in a third device on the circuit and there's a problem for sure. This question doesn't state that the outlet is on a dedicated circuit.

I think those plugs are made for assumed clearance benefit.
For quite some time the code has required kitchen circuits be 20A.
The NEC has rules about whether these appliances should share a 20A circuit that depend on if either is "fastened in place":

210.23 Permissible Loads, Multiple-Outlet Branch Circuits In no case shall the load exceed the branch-circuit ampere rating. A branch
circuit supplying two or more outlets or receptacles shall...
(B) 15- And 20-Ampere Branch Circuits... (click link for omitted details)
(1) Cord-and-Plug-Connected Equipment Not Fastened in Place The rating
of any one cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not fastened
in place shall not exceed 80 percent of the branch-circuit ampere
rating.
(2) Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place The total rating of
utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires, shall
not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating where
lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not
fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.

900w is less than 50% so the microwave complies mounted or not. I can't guess the amperage of the fridge, but it complies if it draws 16A or less.
So Code doesn't make use of these appliances exclusive to a circuit, so it's not likely the cause for flat plug type.
Also for practical considerations breakers trip in an inverse time curve, so likelihood of tripping depends on length of time you nuke stuff while fridge is running. 110% should never trip, and 125% of rating (25A) should hold for about 5 minutes, and if 25A never trips it would still be within NEMA specs.

You also comply even if they are over 50% each if there are no other receptacles on the circuit, if I'm reading 210.23(2) correctly. And it's useful to note that a 900W output microwave probably uses about 1300W.

Could you just use angled flat plug adapters:


If it is a 20A circuit the answer is 'probably'. There's no specific requirement that the microwave or the fridge have a dedicated circuit that I am aware of. The fridge and built-in microwave in my house are on a single 20A circuit and it has never been an issue. Based on nameplate ratings they peak at 2000 watts of the available 2400 watts. Check your nameplates to confirm.
If it's a 15A circuit you might get nuisance trips. Add up the nameplate ratings to have a better idea if that will work.
